# Three.js How to remove gradient voxel?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to draw rectangles with vertex colors.
Currently I am facing strange problem.

[image]

I want smooth gradient, but It is showing strange voxel.

Here is my code link here

[https://jsfiddle.net/LiZhengXian8824/0gnkob4x/94/]

I hope you help me on it.

Comment: But what is the expected result?

Comment: Thank you for replying, Currently I am drawing rectangle with Triangles, but I hope the gradient smooth.